# Customize UI of Share Intent

Tags: android

[image]

I have a share intent in my Android application and I was wondering how can I customize its UI.
I've scanned through a couple of relevant questions here on Stackoverflow and most of them talk about showing specific set of applications to be shown. I don't want that. I want the OS to be the judge of apps it'd show in the share intent view but I do want to look like a certain way. Like the image I've attached with this question.
Moreover, is there a way to make it a custom UI and not have to handle the click events on my own?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How exactly would you think creating a custom UI but not handling the click events from your custom UI would work?

Comment: I wouldn't know. Very new to the Android universe. It was a general wondering of sort. Mainly, I want to customize the UI of share intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are welcome to create your own "chooser", using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to determine the candidate activities to show. When the user chooses one, you can then create an explicit `Intent`, based upon your original implicit `Intent` (e.g., `ACTION_SEND`) and the `ComponentName` of the activity the user chose. Then you are in complete control over the look of the chooser and handling any events.

For example, this activity (from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot)) implements a home screen-style launcher using this technique:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.launchalot;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Launchalot extends ListActivity {
  AppAdapter adapter=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    Intent main=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

    main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);

    Collections.sort(launchables,
                     new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm)); 

    adapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,
                                 int position, long id) {
    ResolveInfo launchable=adapter.getItem(position);
    ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
    ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                         activity.name);
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    i.setComponent(name);

    startActivity(i);    
  }

  class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {
    private PackageManager pm=null;

    AppAdapter(PackageManager pm, List<ResolveInfo> apps) {
      super(Launchalot.this, R.layout.row, apps);
      this.pm=pm;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                          ViewGroup parent) {
      if (convertView==null) {
        convertView=newView(parent);
      }

      bindView(position, convertView);

      return(convertView);
    }

    private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
      return(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
    }

    private void bindView(int position, View row) {
      TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

      label.setText(getItem(position).loadLabel(pm));

      ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

      icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm));
    }
  }
}
```

In your case, you would use your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, rather than `ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_HOME`, but the same principle applies.

Comment: Great. How can I call it on click event of share button in my app?
I have implemented click event for the share button via `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Comment: @BasitSaeed: I do not know what "the share button" is. If you mean a `ShareActionProvider`, you would remove it and do something else, or you would fork it and rewrite it.

Comment: A share button is an action button I put on the action bar.

Comment: @BasitSaeed: In `onOptionsItemSelected()`, you are welcome to launch an activity or display a dialog that contains your "chooser" UI, using the general techniques outlined in my answer.

Comment: can you guide me a little bit on how do I load an actual share intent to send data to the selected app from the list?

Comment: @BasitSaeed: You used an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` with `queryIntentActivities()`. Just take that `Intent` and call `setComponent()` and optionally `setFlags()`, as is shown in the `onListItemClick()` method in the source code in the answer. Then, call `startActivity()` on that `Intent`.

Comment: @BasitSaeed: I already have a sample of building an `Intent` using `setComponent()` based on the user's choice of an activity. It is the `onListItemClick()` method in the sample that I pasted into the answer. I pointed this out in the answer, and in my previous comment.

Comment: Isn't it already done in the code? So what am I missing here?

Comment: @BasitSaeed: "So what am I missing here?" -- how should I know?

Comment: What I mean to say was, your suggestion is kind of declared in the sample code so why isn't it passing data to the application that is opened when an activity is selected from the share intent?

Comment: @BasitSaeed: In my case, there is no data, because `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` activities do not use `Uri` values or extras.

Comment: Yes, so how to implement them? How to send data to the activity we're selecting from the list?

Comment: @BasitSaeed: Call `setDataAndUri()` and `putExtra()` on the `Intent`, just like you would on an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` you were just going to use with the regular system chooser.

Comment: I did do that but it didn't send anything with `putExtra()`.

Comment: @BasitSaeed: I suggest that you open a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you post your code and explain your symptoms.

Comment: I would but it directly relates to this question and the sample code provided by you.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, Thanks for your comment. I have one query here. How to show direct share(Android version >= Marshmallow) contacts in this scenario? I couldn't find any solution for this because for ChooserTargetService, we need to invoke createChooser. Pls update if there is any other way for this.

Comment: @VikramBhati: I do not know if that is an option. I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question on this, assuming that one has not already been asked.